# glsl demo suggestions?

Tags: opengl, rendering, shaders, glsl

In a lot of places I interviewed recently, I have been asked many a times if I have worked with shaders. Even though, I have read and understand the pipeline, the answer to that question has been no. Recently, one of the places asked me if I can send them a sample of 'something' that is "visually polished".

So, I decided to take the plunge and wrote some simple shader in GLSL(with opengl).I now have a basic setup where I can use vbos with glsl shaders.

I have a very short window left to send something to them and I was wondering if someone  with experience, could suggest an idea that is interesting enough to grab someone's attention.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of demo ? Just a render, or something in real time, or an interactive demo ?

Comment: More the merrier is always better :) I have a lot of code, and programmer art, so the folks are little concerned and wanted just something *shiny*. For simplicity, I think a render/ something in realtime would work.

Answer (score 10):

Everybody saw phong implemented. So how about:

- **water** - there are tons of tutorials and it looks always great
- **shadow mapping** - absolute basic in game dev. Multipass rendering is good thing to show. You can improve it with some kind of soft shadows (i highly recommend [PCSS](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/shaderlibrary/docs/shadow_PCSS.pdf) - easy effective or [Variance Shadow Maps](http://www.punkuser.net/vsm/))
- **bumpmapping**
- **parallax mapping** - looks cool, and pretty easy if you got bump mapping done.
- **geometry shaders** (if you do hairs/fur over the polygon - could be based on lines or billboards - they will love you :)) - [whitepaper from nvidia](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10/direct3d/Source/Fur/doc/FurShellsAndFins.pdf)
- **mirrors**
- **post process** - cartoon shader, old camera shader

Comment: what is the old camera shader ?

Comment: Heh, thats something super simple. Just desaturation, maybe sepia look and some random placed "old camera" textures added thru additive blending (it sucks, but may impress somebody :])

Comment: Another thing you might want to look at is materials. Implement one or several shading models efficiently (car paint, plastic). Learn about BRDF:s while doing so. Skinning is also quite often done in the vertex program so that might be something to look at.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for all the suggestions. I'm working on water-effect right now. I'll keep it open for now, in-case if anyone else wants to add some suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

How about [metaballs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFulkoGg9C0&NR=1) ? They make for a pretty interesting demo and there is a lot you can do with shading like point lights, reflection, refraction and so on.
There is also the classic terrain + water demo, in which you can have texturing, shades, displacement mapping (for the water), reflection...

Comment: Nice idea. Looks great in 3D as well: http://vimeo.com/groups/glsl/videos/10271624

Answer (score 1):

I work for a school project on a rendering real time demo. Here a link to the video :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gj4vvlWuL8E
You will find a a link to the source code too if you are interrested. It has lots of shader effect, like water, shadow, parralax toon, motion blur, depth of field etc...

Comment: looks pretty awesome +1

Answer (score 0):

Actually making this work is way out of my depth (and it's DX11 and not OpenGL) but I found this article on Bokeh and DOF effects fascinating, and the results look really good :

[How To Fake Bokeh (And Make It Look Pretty Good)](http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2011/02/28/bokeh/)

There's a follow-up [here](http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/bokeh-ii-the-sequel/) too if you're interested.

Another suggestion would be a good HDR tone-mapping algorithm, for example [from Uncharted 2's John Hable's blog](http://filmicgames.com/archives/75#more-75).